# angular js : set option value after filling options in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web service which has result like:

```
{
    "selectedStateId": "1",
    "selectedCityId": "1",
    "selectedAreaId": "1",
    "states": [{
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
        "cityId": "1",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
        "cityId": "2",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
        "areaId": "1",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
        "areaId": "2",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
        "areaId": "3",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
}
```

Now, I want to bind arrays of states, cities and areas to three different `select` and set its value using stateId, cityId and areaId that are member of parent object.

Two questions:

1. how to set values of three different `select`s ?
2. How can we achieve (1) if we have array of the objects, the one I have created above ?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I guess the first two answers got some misunderstanding.. So, changed my data representation. I want to set `selectedStateId` to be set into `select` element of states, `selectedCityId` to be set into `select` element of cities, and so on.. Now, I guess you should be clear what I am asking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have created a plunker for you. Please have a look at it with html having 3 selects

```
<select>....</select>
```

"http://plnkr.co/edit/LaypSCATZyQxLHYHjgnB?p=preview"

Comment: I am sorry but this is not working as expected... As I said, I want to set stateId, cityId, and areaId from the parent object (I mean the object which I am having in my response). I am able to set options values using `ng-repeat` but being able to set values from the response object (not the object in array)

Comment: I have updated the plunker. Please review again "http://plnkr.co/edit/LaypSCATZyQxLHYHjgnB?p=preview"

Comment: Thanks.. Your updated plunker was, what I wanted... :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright if you want to create three select from above array each for area , city and states then do following :

Your above response goes like this :

```
$scope.items =  response;
//set default . I am setting first state as default
$scope.selectedstate  = response.states[0];
```

Let's say for states it would be

```
<select 
  ng-options="state.stateName as state.label for state in items.states track by state.stateId"
 ng-model="selectedstate">
```

Follow same process for area and city.

For your reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions . Angular way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way with [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope){
 
  $scope.data = {
    "selectedStateId": "1",
    "selectedCityId": "1",
    "selectedAreaId": "1",
    "states": [{
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
        "cityId": "1",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
        "cityId": "2",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
        "areaId": "1",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
        "areaId": "2",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
        "areaId": "3",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="data.selectedStateId" ng-options="s.stateId as s.stateName for s in data.states" ></select>  
  <select ng-model="data.selectedCityId" ng-options="c.cityId as c.cityName for c in data.cities" ></select>  
  <select ng-model="data.selectedAreaId" ng-options="a.areaId as a.areaName for a in data.areas" ></select>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am trying to answer my own question. for those who expect detailed explanation:

**Answer for question 1:**

To set selected value for `select` element, we just need to set `ng-selected`property to `option`as below:

Suppose my response is:

```
$scope.x = {
    "selectedStateId": "1",
    "selectedCityId": "1",
    "selectedAreaId": "1",
    "states": [{
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
        "cityId": "1",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
        "cityId": "2",
        "stateId": "1",
        "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
        "areaId": "1",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
        "areaId": "2",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
        "areaId": "3",
        "cityId": "1",
        "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
};
```

Then, in html, we can write like:

```
<select>
<option ng-selected="{{state.stateId == x.selectedStateId}}" ng-repeat="state in x.states" value="{{state.stateId}}">{{state.stateName}}</option>
</select>
<select>
<option ng-selected="{{city.cityId == x.selectedCityId}}" ng-repeat="city in x.cities" value="{{city.cityId}}">{{city.cityName}}</option>
</select>
<select>
<option ng-selected="{{area.areaId == x.selectedAreaId}}" ng-repeat="area in x.areas" value="{{area.areaId}}">{{area.areaName}}</option>
</select>
```

**Answer for question 2:**

Suppose, we have array of this object, say,

```
$scope.list = [{
    "stateId": "1",
    "cityId": "1",
    "areaId": "1",
    "states": [{
      "stateId": "1",
      "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
      "stateId": "2",
      "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
      "cityId": "1",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
      "cityId": "2",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
      "areaId": "1",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
      "areaId": "2",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
      "areaId": "3",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
  },
  {
    "stateId": "2",
    "cityId": "2",
    "areaId": "2",
    "states": [{
      "stateId": "1",
      "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
      "stateId": "2",
      "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
      "cityId": "1",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
      "cityId": "2",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
      "areaId": "1",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
      "areaId": "2",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
      "areaId": "3",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
  },
  {
    "stateId": "1",
    "cityId": "2",
    "areaId": "3",
    "states": [{
      "stateId": "1",
      "stateName": "Gujarat"
    }, {
      "stateId": "2",
      "stateName": "Rajasthan"
    }],
    "cities": [{
      "cityId": "1",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Ahmedabad"
    }, {
      "cityId": "2",
      "stateId": "1",
      "cityName": "Surat"
    }],
    "areas": [{
      "areaId": "1",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "thaltej"
    }, {
      "areaId": "2",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Maninagar"
    }, {
      "areaId": "3",
      "cityId": "1",
      "areaName": "Naranpura"
    }]
  }];
```

In this case, we need a wrapper to wrap all the selects so that we can iterate list over it.

So, I took a simple `<div>..</div>` that will do in my case, as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in list">
    <select>
    <option ng-selected="{{state.stateId == x.stateId}}" ng-repeat="state in x.states" value="{{state.stateId}}">{{state.stateName}}</option></select>
    <select>
    <option ng-selected="{{city.cityId == x.cityId}}" ng-repeat="city in x.cities" value="{{city.cityId}}">{{city.cityName}}</option></select>
    <select>
    <option ng-selected="{{area.areaId == x.areaId}}" ng-repeat="area in x.areas" value="{{area.areaId}}">{{area.areaName}}</option></select>
</div>
```